# Parenthesis disappears when I use align environment

Tags: equations, formatting, align

I have an long equation that I must break. However, when I do so, a set of parenthesis disappears. Furthermore, the formation of the equation is odd. What should I do? As you will see in the image, the first equation seems ok, but it's the second one. The red marking shows the missing parenthesis. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Dot{x}}\right)-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=F &&\Rightarrow \left(2m_0+2m_1+2m_2\right)\Ddot{x}+\left(L_1m_1\cos\theta_2+2L_1m_2\cos\theta_1\right)\Ddot{\theta}_1\\
&\:&&+\left(L_1m_1\sin\theta_1+2L_1m_2\sin\theta_1\right)\Dot{\theta}_1^2+\left(L_2m_2\sin\theta_2\right)\Dot{\theta}_2^2=2F\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%SECOND EQUATION%%%%%%%%%%%%
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\Dot{\theta}_1}\right)-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\theta_1}=0&&\Rightarrow\left(12\,m_{1}\,\cos\theta_1+24\,m_{2}\,\cos\theta_1\right)\Ddot{x}+\left(2\,m_{1}+15\,L_{1}\,m_{1}\\
 &\:&&+24\,L_{1}\,m_{2}-9\,L_{1}\,m_{1}\,\cos\left(2\,\theta_{1}\right)\right)\Ddot{\theta}_1+\left(12\,L_{2}\,m_{2}\,\cos\left(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}\right)\right)\Ddot{\theta}_2\\
 &\:&&+\left(9\,L_{1}\,m_{1}\,\sin\left(2\,\theta _{1}\right)\right)\Dot{\theta}_1^2+\left(12\,L_{2}\,m_{2}\,\sin\left(\theta _{1}-\theta _{2}\right)\right)\Dot{\theta}_2^2\\
 &\:&&-12\,g\,m_{1}\,\sin\theta _{1}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't ignore errors. You can't have \left/\right on different lines.

Answer (score 2):

As @UlrikeFischer has already noted in a comment, your code contains a syntax error, as `\left` and `\right` mustn't span line breaks.

The simplest fix is to get rid of almost all `\left` and `\right` sizing modifiers, especially since they don't actually do anything (other than to create a syntax error.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\smash[b]{\frac{d}{dt}
 \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Dot{x}}\right)
 -\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=F }\Rightarrow{}
& (2m_0+2m_1+2m_2)\Ddot{x}
 +(L_1m_1\cos\theta_2+2L_1m_2\cos\theta_1)\Ddot{\theta}_1\notag\\
&\quad+
  (L_1m_1\sin\theta_1+2L_1m_2\sin\theta_1)\Dot{\theta}_1^2
+(L_2m_2\sin\theta_2)\Dot{\theta}_2^2\notag\\
&= 2F\\
%%
\smash[b]{\frac{d}{dt}
 \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\Dot{\theta}_1}\right)
 -\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\theta_1}=0}\Rightarrow{}
&(12m_{1}\cos\theta_1+24m_{2}\cos\theta_1)\Ddot{x}
 +\bigl[2m_{1}+15L_{1}m_{1}+24L_{1}m_{2}\notag\\
&\quad-\phantom{(}9L_{1}m_{1}
 \cos(2\theta_{1})\bigr]\Ddot{\theta}_1
+(12L_{2}m_{2}\cos(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}))\Ddot{\theta}_2\notag\\
&\quad+(9L_{1}m_{1}\sin(2\theta _{1}))\Dot{\theta}_1^2
      +(12L_{2}m_{2}\sin(\theta _{1}-\theta _{2}))\Dot{\theta}_2^2\notag\\
&\quad-12gm_{1}\sin\theta _{1}\notag\\
&=0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this variant layout, to avoid overfull boxes. It requires the `nccmath` package (to be loaded before `mathtools`). I removed the unnecessary  `\left...\right` pairs, and replaced the others with the `bigl ... \bigr` pair. Last, I used the `diffcoeff` package to simplify the  typing of derivatives in Leibniz notation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
 & \begin{alignedat}{2}%
  & \diff*{\biggl(\diffp{\mathcal{L}}{\Dot{x}}\biggr)}{t} & & -\diffp{\mathcal{L}}{x} = F\Rightarrow \\
 & & & \phantom{{}+{}}(2m_0+2m_1+2m_2)\Ddot{x}+(L_1m_1\cos\theta_2+2L_1m_2\cos\theta_1)\Ddot{\theta}_1\\
 & & & +(L_1m_1\sin\theta_1+2L_1m_2\sin\theta_1)\Dot{\theta}_1^2+(L_2m_2\sin\theta_2)\Dot{\theta}_2^2=2F
\end{alignedat}\\[2ex]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%SECOND EQUATION%%%%%%%%%%%%
 & \begin{alignedat}{2}
 & \diff*{\biggl(\diffp{\mathcal{L}}{\Dot{\theta_1}}\biggr)}{t} & & -\diffp{\mathcal{L}}{\theta_1}=0\Rightarrow \\%
 & & &\phantom{{}+{}}(12\,m_{1}\,\cos\theta_1+ 24\,m_{2}\,\cos\theta_1)\Ddot{x}\\ %
 & & & + \bigl(2\,m_{1}+15\,L_{1}\,m_{1}+24\,L_{1}\,m_{2}-9\,L_{1}\,m_{1}\,\cos 2\,\theta_{1}\bigr)\Ddot{\theta}_1\\
 & & & +\bigl(12\,L_{2}\,m_{2}\,\cos(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})\bigr)\Ddot{\theta}_2 +(9\,L_{1}\,m_{1}\,\sin 2\,\theta _{1})\Dot{\theta}_1^2\\
 & & & +\bigl(12\,L_{2}\,m_{2}\,\sin(\theta _{1}-\theta _{2})\bigr)\Dot{\theta}_2^2-12\,g\,m_{1}\,\sin\theta _{1}=0
 \end{alignedat}
\end{align}
 \end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Zarko!

Comment: +1! Is the `mathtools` necessary? I wasn't aware for `diffcoeff` ...

Comment: Here, it's not necessary, but it's loaded, because I  tried other solutions using it (initially, I tried `\MoveEqLeft[some number]`, and finally decided  it was simpler to use use the `fleqn` environment). But I think it's recommendable to load it systematically (except for very simple layouts), because it completes `amsmath` with some quite valuable command/environments.